# Javascript iterate through <li> list and assign event (onitemclick) handlers not working - why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, event-handling, dom-events

My mission in this exercise is to toggle the "done" attribute of the li items on the list whenever someone clicks on them. I found other ways of doing so, but this one didn't work for me and I'm eager to understand why. What's wrong with my code? isn't it possible to assign handlers like that, or maybe something else in my code is wrong?

```js
var liList = document.querySelectorAll("li");
for (var i = 0; i < liList.length; ++i){
    liList[i].onItemClick = function() {
    liList[i].classList.toggle("done");
    }
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>Notebook</li>
   <li>Jello</li>
   <li>Spinach</li>
   <li>Rice</li>
   <li>Birthday Cake</li>
   <li>Candles</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var liList = document.querySelectorAll("li");

for (var i = 0; i < liList.length; ++i){
    liList[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("done");
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you, it worked just like I wanted. Just wanted to ask - what are the rules regarding the use of "this" in javascript? everytime I assign a function to an event handler, "this" will refer to the object being clicked/hovered/etc?

Comment: Basically 'this' keyword refer the current element inside the loop on click event.

Answer (score 2):

use 'onClick' instead of 'onItemClick'

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(function(v){
    v.addEventListener("click", function(e){
      e.target.classList.toggle("done");
    })
  })
})
```

```css
li.done {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Notebook</li>
  <li>Jello</li>
  <li>Spinach</li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Birthday Cake</li>
  <li>Candles</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hi, so in your solution the v handed over to the function is the html object being selected?  and what's the e? I'm new to js and can't really tell the rules about all that information being handed over to functions.

Comment: @user2396866 yes, `v` is the html object, and `e` is the event object, when an `li` is clicked, an event is raised, `e` holds that event information, `e.target` holds the HTML object on which event was raised.

Comment: and like i've already realized, everytime something "holds" an item, changing the something changes the item itself, right? thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try liList[i].onclick = function(e) {console.log(e.currentTaget)}

the e will be your current clicked item.

Answer (score 0):

```
**This may be helpful for you**

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var liList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for(var i=0; i<liList.length; i++){
     liList[i].addEventliListener("click", liClick);
    }
    function liClick(){
      this.classliList.toggle("done");
    }
    </script>
```